# Twilio - STUN / TURN URL

Tags: objective-c, twilio, stun, turn, ice-protocol

I'd like to give the Twilio STUN/TURN a test within my iOS app, currently using another framework for WebRTC video connections.

Below are the STUN / TURN settings I use in the framework. I've looked around the Twilio docs, but I can't seem to find the URL needed to connect, or what login credentials I would use to deploy their service in my case, below:

```
    NSURL *stunUrl =
    [NSURL URLWithString:@"turn:numb.viagenie.ca"];
    QBICEServer* stunServer =
    [QBICEServer serverWithURL:stunUrl
                      username:@"myemail@email.com"
                      password:@"xxxxxxxx"];

    NSURL *turnUDPUrl =
    [NSURL URLWithString:@"turn:numb.viagenie.ca:3478?transport=udp"];
    QBICEServer *turnUDPServer =
    [QBICEServer serverWithURL:turnUDPUrl
                      username:@"myemail@email.com"
                      password:@"xxxxxxxx"];

    NSURL *turnTCPUrl =
    [NSURL URLWithString:@"turn:numb.viagenie.ca:3478?transport=tcp"];
    QBICEServer* turnTCPServer =
    [QBICEServer serverWithURL:turnTCPUrl
                      username:@"myemail@email.com"
                      password:@"xxxxxxxx"];
```

Does anyone with Twilio STUN/TURN experience know where I could find this information?

Answer (score 3):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can use the STUN server with just the URL: stun:global.stun.twilio.com:3478?transport=udp

For the TURN server, you need to request an ephemeral token which will give you access. The documentation for this can be found here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/token